# Elasticsearch SQL fails to apply multiple filter conditions

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I'm struggling to apply multiple filter conditions to an Elasticsearch SQL query. Here's a reproducible example. It uses R *elastic* package for the setup.

**Setup**

```
require(tidyverse)
require(elastic)

con = connect(warn = FALSE)

index_create(con, 'test')
#> $acknowledged
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $shards_acknowledged
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $index
#> [1] "test"

# "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_second"

mapping = '{
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "text" },
    "data": { 
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "cat": { "type": "keyword" },
        "value": { "type": "integer" },
        "name": { "type": "text" }
      }
    }
  }
}'

mapping_create(con, 'test', body = mapping)
#> $acknowledged
#> [1] TRUE
# mapping_get(con, 'test')

j = '[
  {"id":"1", "data":[
    {"cat":"A", "value":1, "name":"Jane"},
    {"cat":"A", "value":2, "name":"Fred"},
    {"cat":"B", "value":3, "name":"Amy"},
    {"cat":"B", "value":4, "name":"Joe"}
  ]},
  {"id":"2", "data":[
    {"cat":"A", "value":4, "name":"Mary"},
    {"cat":"A", "value":3, "name":"Ned"},
    {"cat":"B", "value":2, "name":"Bill"},
    {"cat":"B", "value":1, "name":"Sue"}
  ]},
  {"id":"3", "data":[
    {"cat":"A", "value":1, "name":"Will"},
    {"cat":"A", "value":1, "name":"Rose"},
    {"cat":"B", "value":4, "name":"Cat"},
    {"cat":"B", "value":4, "name":"Elsa"}
  ]}
]'

dat = jsonlite::fromJSON(j) |> tidyr::unnest(data) |> dplyr::group_split(id)
dat = purrr::map(dat, ~ list(id = .x$id[1], data = select(.x, -id)))
docs_bulk(conn = con, x = dat, index = 'test', es_ids = FALSE)

Search(con, index = "test", q = '*', asdf = TRUE)$hits$hits
  _index _type _id _score _source.id                                  _source.data
1  test  _doc   1      1          1  A, A, B, B, 1, 2, 3, 4, Jane, Fred, Amy, Joe
2  test  _doc   2      1          2  A, A, B, B, 4, 3, 2, 1, Mary, Ned, Bill, Sue
3  test  _doc   3      1          3 A, A, B, B, 1, 1, 4, 4, Will, Rose, Cat, Elsa
```

Querying

For querying I'm using the Elastic *Dev Tools* console. The following works:

```
POST _sql
{
"query": """
    SELECT id, data.cat, data.value, data.name FROM test
    WHERE data.value = 3
  """
}
```

returns

```
{
  "columns" : [
    {
      "name" : "id",
      "type" : "text"
    },
    {
      "name" : "data.cat",
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    {
      "name" : "data.value",
      "type" : "integer"
    },
    {
      "name" : "data.name",
      "type" : "text"
    }
  ],
  "rows" : [
    [
      "1",
      "B",
      3,
      "Amy"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "A",
      3,
      "Ned"
    ]
  ]
}
```

However two terms:

```
POST _sql
{
"query": """
    SELECT id, data.cat, data.value, data.name FROM test
    WHERE data.value = 3 AND data.cat = 'A'
  """
}
```

I expect elastic to just return `Ned` but instead we get:

```
{
  "columns" : [
    {
      "name" : "id",
      "type" : "text"
    },
    {
      "name" : "data.cat",
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    {
      "name" : "data.value",
      "type" : "integer"
    },
    {
      "name" : "data.name",
      "type" : "text"
    }
  ],
  "rows" : [
    [
      "1",
      "A",
      1,
      "Jane"
    ],
    [
      "1",
      "A",
      2,
      "Fred"
    ],
    [
      "1",
      "B",
      3,
      "Amy"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "A",
      4,
      "Mary"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "A",
      3,
      "Ned"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What is going wrong here?